# pre-code and post-code specifications in array package combining poorly with multirow package

Tags: tables, multirow

I have a long table where every single cell has to be formatted in math mode and enclosed between the same code, i.e. `$\{\ldots,<cell>,\ldots\}$`.
To avoid repeating I'm using the feature from the `array` package that lets you specify code to be inserted before and after each cell contents, i.e. `>{code}Mc<{code}`.

However, this combines poorly with the `\multirow` command, because while the content of the spanning cell seems to be correctly centered between the two rows, the code is inserted twice. Furthermore, it seems I have to put content into math mode again to make it work.

Here is a minimal example:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}

    \newcolumntype{L}{>{$\{\ldots,} c <{,\ldots\}$}}

    \begin{tabular}{L L} \hline
        \alpha & \beta \\
        \multirow{2}{*}{$\gamma$} & \delta \\
                                  & \eta \\\hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

with the result:
[image: mwe]

So is it possible to combine `\multirow` with these kind of column specification?

Comment: So isn't there a badge for "You asked the first TeX.SE question that was not answered wonderfully in less than 20 minutes" ?? XD

Comment: No, but the `Tumbleweed` badge is ahead :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The call `\multirow{<n>}{*}{<text>}` works essentially in this way:

1. the argument `<text>` is typeset in a box;
2. the boxed is shifted down to emulate centering with respect to `<n>` rows;
3. the shifted box is handed to `tabular`.

It's only after step 3 that the pre-text and post-text are added. Such texts are also added when the cell is empty.

Note that `\multirow` is not aware at all about the column type. Not even of being in `array` rather than `tabular`. So the argument is always assumed in text mode.

So, if you plan to use `\multirow` in a column, either be prepared to use `\multicolumn{1}{...}{...}{\multirow{2}{*}{...}}` and `\multicolumn{1}{c}{}` for every empty cell or don't use pre-text and post-text in the column.

Annoying? Perhaps. But I've long come to the conclusion that tables very rarely, if ever, need `\multirow`.

```
\documentclass[border=4pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multirow}

\newcommand{\foo}[1]{$\{\dots,#1,\dotsc\}$}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{c c}
\hline
\foo{\alpha} & \foo{\beta} \\
\multirow{2}{*}{\foo{\gamma}} & \foo{\delta} \\
             & \foo{\eta} \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: egreg, but in this way you have to change all the cell, with my dirty fix only the ones involved in the `multirow`...

Comment: @CarLaTeX Sure! I just wanted to show what I believe is a cleaner method, albeit heavier to use.

Comment: I also think that this is more elegant, but if the actual table has a lot of cells it's not convenient. Let's see what the OP preferes :):):)

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this solution could be acceptable for you, but I've used a couple of fake `multicolumn`s and explicity added the post/pre code to the `multirow`.

I've also added a couple of rows just to show that you don't need to modify the single rows.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}

    \newcolumntype{L}{>{$\{\ldots,} c <{,\ldots\}$}}

    \begin{tabular}{L L} \hline
        \alpha & \beta \\
        \multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{2}{*}{$\{\ldots, \gamma ,\ldots\}$}} & \delta \\
        \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \eta \\
        \alpha & \beta \\
        \alpha & \beta \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]